# Angular 6 and Spring boot - can't get data using simple HttpClient call

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, rxjs, angular6

I'm trying to get user in angular 6 service like this:

```
this.http.get<User>('http://localhost:8080/test', {observe: 'response'})
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

The code for backend part is following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public User test() {
        log.info("Test controller");
        return new User(1, "VR", "123123", "A",
                "B", "123", "a@a.com", true, true, 4);
    }
}
```

The problem is that despite everything seems ok, I can use backend rest service from postman, browser, but I don't get anything in frontend part.

I put breakpoints to `console.log(data);` and to `console.log(error);` and it jut doesn't stop there!

Where did I go wrong? I'm still pretty new to Anular and frontend development.
I tried to disable security for REST endpoint I use but still same results.

I tried it via `.pipe(...)` but with same results.

Oh, yes, in similar code during my attempts to make it work I got `error` just as `OK` string without any further info.

I explored packages via wireshark and everything seems to be ok to me.

I'm stuck.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the browser devtools network tab to see whats happening ? Did you think of using the proxy configuration in the  `proxy.conf.json` ?

Comment: Are your back-end and front-end models for User the same? Try removing the `<User>` cast from your get call and see if that gives any result.

Comment: Can you put all code from your service and paste any errors from the console?

Comment: @ibenjelloun Two requests to server, first OPTIONS, second GET itself, both with status 200. JWT token is present in GET response. Never used angula proxy, will read about it and try.

Comment: @GijsPost Thank you so much, your comment helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gijs Post pointed me to correct answer: back-end and front-end models for `User` were not the same. Fixing this resolved issue.